# Deleting a question that's likely to be unimportant very soon

Tags: discussion, deleting, too-localized

I asked a question about a possible bug in [hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3146/647). Looks like this bug is likely to disappear in a few days, rendering this question pretty worthless except for the few people who installed TeX Live 2010 during the time frame of the bug.

Should I delete this question now? When the bug is fixed? Some point after? Never?

Comment: *except for the few people who installed TeX Live 2010 during the time frame of the bug* - I'm guessing more than a few, and that you'd surprised at how long these old, buggy version linger.

Comment: I guess it depends on when the fix comes out. Unless this bug predates this particular version of `hyperref` (and it might, I don't know), we're talking about four days (so far) during which people would encounter this bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, this surfaced just after Texlive had been announced as ready for burning to DVD.  I'm guessing a fair few people took that as their cue to upgrade.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I’d not delete it, as it might be helpful to someone (I think most people don’t update their TeX installation regularly). When the fix is released, please add (and accept) an answer with info in which version it was fixed.

Comment: Closing is ok, but please don't delete it. And adding an answer is important so that it doesn't appear in the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say “delete”.

Comment: It's better to change the text of the question, rather than add an answer, so that the information is right up where the future reader starts reading.

Comment: Definitely the best thing to do. Adding a clear **Edit** or **Update** note in the question pointing to the release that fixed the bug.

Comment: An answer is needed, so that the answer doesn’t count as unanswered. Alternatively, close it.

Answer (score 3):

keep it!
bug history is useful for those who do not update, or do it out of time. add an update with link for update and describe the problem.

Mateus Araújo remark has a point!

don't if this is possible - but add to the question tittle the time frame or the update for which the answers are useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say never. Distinguishing a "worthless" question from a nice/good/great one can be done by comparing their respective upvotes.

Comment: I was thinking of deleting it as more of a signal:noise improvement. But I guess I'll just accept the answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say delete it when the bug is fixed. The sigal/noise ratio is important: I was trying to find an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312/1035) on the net, and all I could find were references to old url and hyperref bugs. I was confused until I figure that they referred to another problem, but nonetheless I just couldn't google for the right question, as there were so many wrong ones. In the end I gave up and discovered the answer experimenting by myself.

Comment: Not a good idea: the bug might be fixed *somewhere*, but that doesn't mean it no longer exists! Of course, mentioning that this bug has been fixed in such-and-such release would be wise...

Comment: For that one has the changelogs of the package. I don't think it is wise to keep here a bug history; specially in this case, that the bug has lasted less than a month and was never widely distributed. If it was a famous or long-lasting one I might think differently.