# Answer reveals problem is package bug: Delete question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleting

I asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231241/footnote-in-bfseries-new-error-in-newpx-update) to find out if an error I encountered after updating TeXLive was a bug. Even if it was a bug, I needed a short-term solution to continue my work until the package was fixed.

@cfr provided such a solution and also confirmed that it was a bug. I reported it to the package author, who has since fixed it.

**Should I now delete the question, since the error is fixed?** Or might it still be valid for people who have not updated their systems or for the poor Debian repository-package users who will always be two years behind? Or could it serve as an example of how to handle problems that are possibly bugs?

And if I delete it, will I deprive the answerer of deserved reputation?

(Also, do I accept the answer even though the real answer is the fix that the package author provided? Or should I add an answer explaining what the package author fixed?)

Related:

- [What is our policy for reporting bugs (for the TeX family of software) that were discovered on TeX.SE?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/what-is-our-policy-for-reporting-bugs-for-the-tex-family-of-software-that-were)
- [Questions which are bug reports](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2622/questions-which-are-bug-reports)
- [Deleting a question that's likely to be unimportant very soon](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/deleting-a-question-thats-likely-to-be-unimportant-very-soon)

Comment: Okay, I have voted to close my question as being about a bug, as recommended by @yo' et al.

Comment: I apologize to @cfr for not accepting the answer, but I don't want to mislead other people since the package author provided the real answer.

Comment: Not sure about deserved but if you delete the question, I will lose any reputation, yes. [So maybe I'm glad that policy is to close but not delete ;).] But you should definitely accept the fix answer. If it were my question, I'd upvote my answer but accept (and upvote, if appropriate) the fix one. So by the Golden Rule, you don't need to apologise. [Although I might, so maybe you do...!!]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We would typically keep bug-related questions around, but close them. Formerly it was a straight-forward "too localized" closure (which made sense), but now it's more common to vote as being "off topic" with some manual motivation.

That's the "policy" part. From a structural point of view, you can't delete that question, since it has a positive-score answer.

For more information on deletion criteria, see the Meta.SE FAQ [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/168244)

Comment: Indeed, the entire status business here is a bit tricky!

Comment: "... off-topic because it is a bug in the package" close reason seems to work, yeah.

Comment: Note that mods can delete *any* post.